# Regression Trees to Predict Continous Variables in Spark

Tags: pyspark, decision-tree

I want to use PySpark regression trees to predict a continuous variable instead of classifying data.  EG at each terminal node use the mean of the remaining training data.  And the labels are [0, infinity] real numbers.

Is this possible in Spark?  The documentation uses the term regression tree: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-decision-tree.html#regression but it likes the predictors are continuous not what is being predicted.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [this github page](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt), you can see the sample data they are using in the example in the Spark Documentation. If you put it into your local HDFS directory, you can run the following:

```
import MLUtils


data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, 'sample_libsvm_data.txt') 
data.map(lambda x: x.label).distinct().collect()
```

The output of this is `[0.0, 1.0]`. This means that it isn't a regression tree in the sense that the dependent variable is continuous. The features seem to be continuous, but unfortunately not the output. Looks like they have not yet implemented decision trees for continuous y variables.